# How to call instance method of comment class through Article Model ?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :article
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments do
        def posted_comments
            #user_comment is just an attribute of comment.
            collect(&:user_comment)
        end
    end
end
```

to fetch the posted comments :

```
    Article.first.comments.posted_comments 
 => ["Nice article posted", "comment 2 added", "Good article"]
```

Above one is fetching correct results, but I want to have a more compact version.
Something like this:

```
Article.first.posted_comments 
#this should list the collection of comments on the article.
```

Can we do something like this with Rails ActiveRecord ?

Answer (score 0):

For simply solution, you can define method called `posted_comments` that calls nested association as the following:

```
def posted_commments
   self.comments.posted_comments 
end
```

Or, Try the following code:

```
has_many :posted_comments, -> { select("user_comment") }, class_name: "Comment"
```

Comment: I think, we can a simple method inside article.rb file : 
def posted_comments comments.collect(&:user_comment) end
Hence we can simply call, Article.first.posted_comments